# Serial port listener in background C#

Tags: c#, forms, serial-port, console-application, background-process

I have a question , i build a form application in C# but i am not so good in it.
I want to add a new feature to the form that listen to the serial port in the background and that then show the received data in a textbox and this has to be done so long that the appication is running.

I found some code from how to do this for a console application but now i want to change the code so that i can use it in a form , could anyone help me?

```
using System;
using System.IO.Ports;

class PortDataReceived
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM8");

        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 57600;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;

        mySerialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler);

        mySerialPort.Open();

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
        mySerialPort.Close();
    }

    private static void DataReceivedHandler(
                        object sender,
                        SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string indata = sp.ReadExisting();
        Console.WriteLine("Data Received:");
        Console.Write(indata);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the serial port initialization code into the form's `Shown` event handler, copy the `DataReceived` event handler code into the form class an instead of writing to the console, put the data into a text box or so.

Please note that the `DataReceived` handler will be called on a separate thread, so you need to call `this.Invoke` to execute the code that updates your UI on the UI thread. Otherwise you'll get an exception.

Comment: Thx i gonna try that :p

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method invoker delegate and set the text in your `DataRecieved` event.

Example:

```
private static void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string indata = sp.ReadExisting();

    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    { 
        textBox.Text += indata; 
    });  
}
```